# Celery: how to run a chain inside a group?

Tags: python, celery

I try to group multiple Celery chains, like this:

```
my_flow = group(chain(task1.s() | task2.s())(item) for item in items)
```

The tasks are correctly executed by the worker when I call `my_flow()`, but it raise an exception:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 507, in __call__
    return self.apply_async(partial_args, **options)
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 484, in apply_async
    type = self.type
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/celery/canvas.py", line 547, in type
    app = self._app if self._app else self.tasks[0].type.app
AttributeError: 'AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'type'
```

What is the right method to run a chain in a group?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? If so, what was the solution?